# What periods and locations in early European history had evidence based criminal trials?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, law, science, crime

What periods and locations in European history had evidence based criminal trials? I'm interested in creating a medieval role playing setting and some fictional narratives involving crime investigators. However, some periods of early European history relied on trial by ordeal to determine innocence or guilt. Evidence appears to have little place in the proceedings. Do I need to go all the way back to ancient Greek and Roman courts? Do I need to go forward to the Renaissance? Perhaps there were a few medieval European cities with local legal systems that employed modern standards of evidence?

Comment: In France, the formal date after which evidence was supposed to prevails on ordeals in 1261 when Louis IX ordered so : "En 1261, conformément au quatrième concile du Latran, une nouvelle ordonnance royale abolit l'ordalie. Les épreuves par le feu et par l'eau dont l'accusé doit sortir indemne ou les combats dont il doit sortir vainqueur devront maintenant être remplacés par des preuves rationnelles ou testimoniales." https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_IX#Le_roi_justicier_et_diplomate Of course, practice in the Realm in the following centuries may still differ from royal edicts...

Comment: You may also want to check Canon 8 of the Fourth Council of Lateran, 1215. : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_Council_of_the_Lateran

Comment: I think none of them.  Your last line is, I think, the key - did pre-modern course follow modern standards of evidence?    (if they did, we wouldn't call them "modern standards").  I'm not a specialist in this area, but the one example that come to mind is Cicero's prosecution of the governor of Sicily, where he amassed enough evidence to intimidate the plaintiff.  But even there, the court merely wanted testimony about character; evidence was a tactic.

Comment: One could look at the inquisition - while the "crimes" the inquisitors investigated where mostly heresy which we would not regard as crimes of course, they did work with evidence from the defendants texts. The other question is wether criminal trials where a thing in medieval europe.

Comment: Also, you might want to read Umberto Ecos Name of the Rose, which has a hero doing evidence based work in a society that does not think that way.

Comment: @Evargalo when were similar orders announced in other European countries?

Comment: @D.Vyd : once I've time to research this, I'll write a proper answer. My comment was just supposed to help if someone has time to elaborate on it and write a complete answer before I find the necessary time...

Comment: The question is more about what people in which period *considered* to be "evidence". They *always* thought their trials were evidence-based. After all, if a suspect confessed under the ordeal, wasn't that "evidence" of guilt?

Comment: @DevSolar, good point. I'm interested in science-based evidence, witnesses, alibis, etc. Europe is my first choice. If not there, I'd be open to setting the project in the ancient middle east if such a court system existed. That might be a separate question though.

Comment: Does it *have* to be historically correct? The beauty of roleplaying is that you can "tweak" the setting. From a secluded group / sect that is "experimenting" with scientific evidence ("Name of the Rose"), to an alternative history where scientific thinking came a couple centuries early, to a full-blown "what if..."

Comment: @DevSolar, I would be happy to tweak the setting if a historically accurate one is not available.

Comment: @D.Vyd: Then I would suggest, from a RPG campaign view (instead of historian view), pick whatever setting / period "feels" best for you, and go for the group / sect approach. There is a whole lot about the past which we *don't* know, and it is not too big a leap to consider a couple of people eschewing faith, superstition etc. and going for "real" evidence. With the possibility of a nice side-plot when the other side *does* bring up "faith-based evidence", and our protagonists having to argue their way around being considered heretics... ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar, it may be interesting to move the 1261 order in France to a different time and place or to adopt some aspects. I'll wait to see what other people suggest but your ideas are definitely sound.

Comment: The English plea rolls contain no cases of trial by ordeal after 1219, when Henry III recognized its abolition.(*Bartlett, Robert (1986). **Trial by Fire and Water**. Oxford: Oxford University Press. pp. 127–128*) via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_by_ordeal#English_common_law). Of course, *duels* (for redress of civil insults) only slowly disappeared amongst the English elite over another several hundred years.

Comment: they had good reason to trust more witnesses than physical evidence. First, modern forensic testing were not available. Heck, even in XX century, after DNA testing some decades old rape cases were solved. Second, more people would take their word seriously and consider perjury a serious sin. There were a german law such that 12 good citizens as witnesses could invalidate any physical evidence. As they did not believe any bandit could convince 12 good guys to perjure. Some of our traditions also are rooted in the need for witnesses - why do we need a ceremony to hand out diplomas at univ today?

Comment: You might want to check the Salem witch trials, which ended only when the rules of evidence were changed to forbid "spectral evidence".  You are asking two different questions  1) when did trial by ordeal end and 2) when did modern rules of evidence come into being.  There is a huge opportunity for setting design in the gap between those two questions.

Answer (score 2):

### As heretical as this sounds . . . the Inquisition.

Of course this sounds completely counter-intuitive, as the crimes prosecuted by inquisitors were slippery, to say it mildly, and the "evidence" could be as ephemeral as cobwebs.  However, it is precisely because of this that the Inquisition revolutionized the way trials were handled.  Most of what we associate with a proper trial was either invented or popularized by the Inquisition.  That includes proper trial transcripts, professional officers of the law, "modern" ideas of evidence, and limitations on torture.

(On the last point, understand that the common opinion of the time was that you could not trust a statement that *wasn't* made under torture.  The manuals given to inquisitors are among the few documents of the era that instructed otherwise.)

There are several reasons why the Inquisition had such a tremendous impact on legal proceedings.  The crimes being prosecuted were problematic for the conventional courts - the issues were often subtle and the verdicts often had major political and social ramifications.  Many prosecutions involved difficult points of church doctrine, beyond the capacity of an ordinary feudal court to analyze.  A verdict reached too casually could inflame a riot (or even a war ) - "heretic" and "rebel" were often all-but synonymous in a milieu where kings were assumed to be blessed by the divine.  The Inquisition itself was extra-territorial, with avenues of appeal leading all the way to Rome.

Thus there was a lot of pressure on the inquisitors to develop iron-clad verdicts based on unimpeachable evidence, properly documented and derived in a consistent, professional manner.  Of course, it took centuries to develop and was not always successful.

It should not be surprising that over time, the haphazard civil court systems of Europe would be deeply influenced by the much more sophisticated inquisitions.  Standards for how courts were run, transcripts kept, appeals heard, and testimony obtained, inevitably improved in imitation of the evolving model.  In time (mostly the 17th century) the law codes were updated to reflect the new procedures and the ideas that motivated them, and the form of our modern court systems were solidified.

Comment: There may be merit to this argument - but without a comparison to the contemporary development of English Criminal Law from the Anglo-Saxon traditions, through the reforms by Henry II and Magna Carta and then the Tudor reforms including introduction of an impartial jury, I see it as ultimately meaningless.

Comment: [My anser here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/42557/at-what-point-in-england-did-use-of-swords-to-settle-impromptu-arguments-become/42564#42564) might be interesting reading, especially [this reference](https://repository.law.umich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwij-8f30qTYAhXLy4MKHckQC14QFgh4MA4&url=http%3A%2F%2Frepository.law.umich.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D1136%26context%3Darticles&usg=AOvVaw3EKZljnob4opVoUr-szuH5&httpsredir=1&article=1136&context=articles)

Comment: some people would fake to be priests just to escape secular courts and/or ordails and be judged by the Inquisition. (as the inquisition also had jurisdiction on some more crimes when committed by clergy). The inquisition always had very strong limits on torture (e.g. only once and with no blood), while in some secular courts torture was at the discrimination of the judges. Obviously the Inquisition was not happy when they uncovered the fake priest.

Comment: I like the answer, but I would like to see some sources before upvoting.

Comment: another reason for the inquisition was that heresy judgments was not only "problematic" for a secular court, it was canonically forbidden. Canonically only the church can say if someone is a good catholic or judge doctrine officially, otherwise kings would become head of the church. And as the kings would not tolerate heretics anyway, the only juridical option to avoid secular courts judging heresy was to have the church judge the facts and hand over the heretics for the state to punish.

Comment: @andejons  It's what I can do from my work desk before the boss notices.  I don't think the general thrust is controversial, although the *degree* of influence is certainly very debatable and worth further study.  At home I have some books . . .

Comment: @Luiz   Perhaps I should have made more clear the connection between trials for heresy and for rebellion.  An excellent example is that of the Albegensians, in which virtually all heretics were rebels and all rebels were heretics.  The church had an interest in making sure that the distinctions were clear.

Comment: This is a well argued answer. Thank you! I'll keep the question open for another day or so and if no other answer emerges--this will be it!

Comment: he inquisition was my first hunch, but from wikipedia sources alone I could not arrive at your conclusion (why I didn't write an answer). I join the chorus of those asking for sources.

Comment: downvoted for the lack of sources after multiple requests.